# Can EditText jump to next position (timer)?

Tags: android

My timer app (see picture below) seems like a EditText field where i can set numbers (from right to left). After setting  one number it jumps to the one left to it (or if it is its end, it replaced the first number on the right). It also have leading zeros.

So i want to create something like this too, but not with a fixed amount of numbers. Is this possible with a editText or should i use TextView or another element? I tried to use EditText because on focussing it can open a Numpad (i don't want a fixed Numpad).

[image]

Comment: What will you use, apart from numbers for a timer?

Comment: I only want to use it for a timer setting.

Comment: Your requirements are not clear to me!

Comment: Assumed i have 3 numerical `EditText` fields (like in the picture `00:12:34`) and on focussing them i want to open the numpad. if the user types a one (if its "empty"), it should be `01`, then a 2 makes it `12`. A 3 makes it `23` and so on.